# Install Epson XP 102

Tags: drivers, printing

I would like to install an Epson XP 102 but cannot find any drivers...

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Please ask your question in English, please.

Comment: Dag Carla, deze site is alleen in het Engels...

Comment: @Jacobvlijm: I.p.v leuteren: Gewoon vertalen.... ;) :p

Comment: @Fabby That' s not the most friendly thing you've ever said  :) However, In general: either OP will translate it him/herself after the mild suggestion, *or* answers in English will not land too well. That's the reason I do not translate too quickly, even if he or she speaks my language.

Comment: @Jacobvlijm: That's why I put the smileys in there! ;) :) I just translate... They do get the point as well and this way they get answers quicker. >:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download drivers from [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)

Search for your model and download files

```
epson-inkjet-printer-201202w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
```

for 64-bit system or

```
epson-inkjet-printer-201202w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_i386.deb
iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
```

if your system is 32-bit.

Copy these files to your Home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After that go to System Settings -> Printers and install new printer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Ubuntu, where *there are no drivers*.

There is something called "modules" and these serve the same purpose though.

So head to the icon in the upper left corner (the dash), type "printers", double-click the icon, add a printer, choose "Epson" and take the name of the printer that *most closely* resembles yours and in 99% of the cases that'll just work ...

Comment: That will not install scanner drivers. And I am not sure about printer drivers as well. The proprietary drivers used to be available for automatic install but not for all Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Modules! ;) I like open... If the standard, open modules do what she needs, they'll get updated automatically leading to an overall better user experience... :)

Comment: What modules are you talking about. For this printer only proprietary driver works. It can be installed from repository or downloaded manually. There are no any "modules" for that. And do you mean kernel modules or what? Or just "something" called "modules"?

Comment: Drop by the AU General chat room and ping me there...